# moving down a line in c

Tags: c

My goal is to make a program that will be able to replace words from a sentence with alternatives stored in a text file (for instance: "hello sir" will be replaced with "greetings sir" if `hello - greetings` appears on the txt file).

Between reading and storing the entire txt dictionary inside an array of arrays (splitting each row to the words and synonyms) and reading directly from the file, I was thinking of the following solution:

For each word in the text:

Search the word in the file (it will appear in the beginning of each row).  If not found, move to the next line immediately without reading any further (and if found, read a random word from the line and replace with the original).

I would like to know how to move the reader to the next line in the text (without having to read through until reaching /n) if that is possible and doable.

An example of the regular usage and the requested solution:

```
if (file) {
while (fscanf(file, "%s", str)!=EOF)
   if(the word is not found)
     move to the next line without continuing reading.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the whole line, but what is wrong with that?   You can do something like:

```
int ch;
while( (ch=fgetc(file)) != '\n' )
  if(ch == EOF)
      goto end;
```

Comment: Hi,the only reason i am asking is becuase i was wondering what would be more efficent - reading the whole file into the memory and then acessing an array directly from my program or reading from the txt file in this way.

Comment: In general I think memory access (RAM/registers/Cache) is faster than Disk I/O (HDD). Your proposed solution of opening the file and reading it each time will be slower than reading and storing the entire file in memory. One of the cases where the first solution might be better is when your file is huge (i.e much larger than your RAM) in which case you still might want to use something else and better tuned for large database quering.

Comment: thank you,that was my first persumption.so,for this matter,storing the contents of the txt file inside my memory in an array of arrays(using malloc possibly) will be better?